# How do I do an inner join while also joining using the where clause?

Tags: sql, express, join, where-clause

```
select Products.SKU, Products.MPN, Products.Manufacturer, dpi.DLRcost, dpi.msrp, dpi.Quantity, pu.UnitofMeasure, pu.ActualWeight, pu.ShipWeight,     pu.Length, pu.Width, pu.Height
from
(select PartNumber as SKU, MPN, Manufacturer
from ActiveProducts
union select SKU, MFP, Brand 
from ActiveItems
union select SKU, mfr_part_number, manufacturer
from AllProductsCombined
) as Products, DealerPriceInventory dpi, PriceUpdate pu
where Products.sku=dpi.sku AND dpi.sku=pu.SKU
```

I want to left join the results from the above query with another table because not all skus will be in the right table. Is there anyway to accomplish this without inner joining all the tables in this statement?

Answer (score 1):

"New" ANSII syntax has been introduced in 1992 so you are free to use it in your query.

```
...from (...) as Products 
   left join DealerPriceInventory dpi on Products.sku=dpi.sku 
   left join PriceUpdate pu on dpi.sku=pu.SKU
where  <some other conditions>
```

Comment: Ok so thanks for this reply. I did basically did this before and just wanted to condense it. I guess what I don't understand is how you do a left join on dpi to products then do one from dpi to pu. How is this not leaving something out? wouldn't you want to do a join on the result from dpi/products to priceupdate?

Comment: `left join` by definition returns **all** rows from left table and matching rows from the right. non-matching rows are `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would go:

```
with Products as (select PartNumber as SKU, MPN, Manufacturer
from ActiveProducts
union select SKU, MFP, Brand 
from ActiveItems
union select SKU, mfr_part_number, manufacturer
from AllProductsCombined),
NewTable as (select NewColumn,Sku1 from NewTable)

select Products.SKU, Products.MPN, Products.Manufacturer, dpi.DLRcost, 
dpi.msrp, dpi.Quantity, pu.UnitofMeasure, pu.ActualWeight, pu.ShipWeight,
pu.Length, pu.Width, pu.Height, NewTable.NewColumn from Products
left join DealerPriceInventory dpi on Products.sku=dpi.sku   
left join PriceUpdate pu on dpi.sku=pu.SKU
left join NewTable on Products.sku=NewTable.sku1
....
```